# information about .deb installation, many errors

Tags: tar, deb, archive

I want to install  a `tar.gz` file downloaded from [here](https://github.com/X0rg/CPU-X/releases/tag/v4.1.0). I tried but I got an error.

I open the terminal in the folder and I'm trying to install.

Here is a screenshot of the file manager, showing part of the archive contents.

I have Debian 10.

[image]

Comment: What is this error you've mentioned? What have you done/tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to extract three of the `*.deb` files out of the `.tar.gz`:

- `cpu-x_4.1.0+15.1_amd64.deb`, the main program
- `cpuidtool_0.5.0_amd64.deb` a tool used by the CPU-X program
- `libcpuid15_0.5.0_amd64.deb`, a library used by the tool

The rest are debugging symbol files (`-dbgsym`) and development files (`-dev`); those are not needed for running the program, only for debugging it or using the `libcpuid` library in another programming project.

Once you have the the three files extracted, run this command in the directory you've placed them, as root:

```
apt install ./cpuidtool_0.5.0_amd64.deb ./libcpuid15_0.5.0_amd64.deb ./cpu-x_4.1.0+15.1_amd64.deb
```

...and that's it. The `./` in front of the package names is important: it tells `apt` to not try and find the named packages from a repository as normal, but use the package files you have right there.

After that, you should be able to run the program by either running the `cpu-x` command (as a regular user), or by finding the program in your GUI menus (System category, probably).

Comment: thanks a lot for your time and help, very appreciated. You are th best